# We have about 30 questions mentioning Path of War that are not tagged as such. What should we do about them?

Tags: discussion, tags, pathfinder

Using [this search query](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bpath-of-war%5D+path+of+war+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpathfinder%5D), one can find slightly more than 30 questions that clearly mention Path of War, an alternative ruleset for Pathfinder published by Dreamscarred Press, but that are *not* tagged as such. Due to this fact, it's not possible to find them if searching using the [path-of-war](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-war) tag.

What should we do about this situation? Should we leave those questions as they are, or should we add [path-of-war](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-war) to their tag list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Add the tag to questions which are *about* the ruleset

Adding and/or correcting the tags of old questions is useful. The only caveat is to not flood the homepage with such edits. There's no hard rules for what constitutes flooding, but spaced out clusters of half-a-dozen should be safe.

But a question mentioning "Path of War" doesn't always make it *about* Path of War. Specifically, a question about a character option from that book might mention it, but doesn't need the tag. There is in fact guidance for tag usage in the excerpt:

> Use this tag on questions asking specifically about the overall supplement or issues specific to the ruleset, not simply on any question about specific character options from Path of War.

At a quick glance (admittedly from someone not familiar with the system nor book), it looks like several of these are about the ruleset and do deserve the tag, but not all.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an active member of RPG.SE, but in general operations like these are encouraged on Stack Exchange sites, but you should be careful not to flood the homepage with bumped old questions. If you do the retagging at a pace of, say, 4 questions a day, it doesn't cause too much noise and is still finished in a week or so. That also gives you the opportunity to check for other things to improve in the questions and their answers (grammar corrections, broken link checks) without it becoming too much effort.